# Can’t bind 2nd player into RetroPie on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, retropie

I have an arcade run on raspberry pi 3 flashed with RetroPie 4.4.
I have 2 Xin Mo Dual joysticks connected.

- **JoyStick** : Xinmo
- **Controller** : Xinmo USB Encoder

[image]

**Note:**
Both controllers wired perfectly.
I've tested all the buttons on my Windows PC > Control Panel (before plug in the usb into the Pi).

I tried to retroArch and bind user 2

I kept getting.

[image]

> Error saving autoconf file

[image]

Do I need to install any extra driver for it to recognize?

Do I need to run any commands or enabled anything feature on my Pi?

---

## Questions

**How would one go about and debug this further ?**

---

I'm open to any suggestions at this moment.

Any hints/suggestions / helps on this be will be much appreciated!

Comment: That interface used to connect it to RasPi?

Comment: I'll update my post to include the exact model, but I used this one : https://i.imgur.com/dDzTW1n.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to fix the saving error after that I don't have that error anymore.

[image]